# Gluing diagrams for tori

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I know that gluing opposite sides of a square gives a torus, and I think I've seen somewhere that gluing opposite sides of an octagon gives a 2-holed torus.  Is there a general way of constructing gluing diagrams for surfaces of genus $g$ / for $k$-holed-tori?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a depiction of the most common construction:

[image]

Gluing a 4k-gon by grouping the edges into groups of 4 like this produces a k-holed torus. Other gluings of 4k-gons also produce a k-holed torus, as long as they keep the surface orientable and ensure that all 4k vertices are glued together into a single point. This is a consequence of [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Polyhedra) for CW complexes and [the classification theorem for closed 2-manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Classification_of_closed_surfaces). Gluing opposite sides together, as you suggest, works as well.